# Change/reduce time format

Tags: javascript, regex

Im really new to programming and wish to reduce a time format from...

"Sun Oct 13 00:00:00 2013" too "Oct 13 2013".

Whats the best way to do this? would it be through Regex or some sort of substr function?

would the regex be something like (^[Sun][Mon][Tue][Wed][Thu][Fri][Sat][00:00:00])?

It wouldn't be very dynamic if the numbers changed though.. This is so confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date("Sun Oct 13 00:00:00 2013");
date = (date + "").split(" ").slice(1, 4).join(" ");
alert(date);
```

Try this. This will alert `Oct 13 2013` as you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

For instance, you can do:

```
var myDate = new Date("Sun Oct 13 00:00:00 2013");
var y = myDate.getFullYear();
var m = myDate.getMonth();
var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var d = myDate.getDate();
var myFormattedDate = months[m] + ' ' + d + ' ' + y;
```

For better formatting and localization, have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if the format of the input string is as it is on the example:

```
input = input.replace(/.*?([a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d+).*?(\d\d\d\d)/g, "$1 $2");
```

Comment: You can improve the regex: `/.*?([a-zA-Z]{3}\s+\d{1,2}).*?(\d{4})/g`

Comment: Whoa, regex confuses the hell out of me but this worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A quick simple regex would be:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s
```

And replace with `""` (nothing)

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/vL0zJ4

Javascript:

```
timeStr = "Sun Oct 13 00:00:00 2013";
timeStr = timeStr.replace(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s/, "");

console.log(timeStr);
```

Output:

```
Sun Oct 13 2013
```

Comment: Thank you! Allthough this is close I required the weekday removed too but thanks anyways, I now have it working.